# Magento 1.9 localisation package error

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I have created 2 stores in Magento 1.9.3. One for **Spanish** and other for **Catalan** language.
I tried to download language packages:

- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/community-modules-catalan-catalonia-language-pack.html
- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/community-modules-spanish-spain-language-pack.html

But am getting error for both the packages as:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package not found: Locale_Mage_community_es_ES 1.2.0.0.2-beta

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is an error with the packages. It does not work when trying to download it via different channels.
If you don't mind using an older version of the language packs and doing some work to update it you can download them [from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/) or [from here](https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/) and install them manually.

Comment: I downloaded package from here :http://ext.topmage.com/Locale_Mage_community_es_ES.html  but don't know how correct it is.